# Grouping by week date but unable to convert server date to mm/dd/yyyy format using CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which gives the intended results but I am having trouble with using CAST to change the date formatting to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Original code:

```
SELECT
  owneridname,
  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) [week],
  COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [Yes], 
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [No]
FROM incident
WHERE createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
  owneridname,
  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0)
ORDER BY
  Week DESC;
```

Results:

| owneridname | week | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 0 |
| Alexis Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 12 |
| Andrea Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 22 |
| Ashley Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 4 |

I tried `DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, CAST(createdon as date)), 0) [week]` in the SELECT statement and separately `CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date)` under GROUP BY but I receive error messages on both.

Comment: What error messages do you receive? You want to cast the result, not the argument. The second attempt you show should work.

Comment: As an aside a date or datetime has no inherent formatting, they are stored in binary format, ssms has a default format to display them, but that's not how they are stored.

Comment: I have to say I'm not a fan of using 0 as a minimum date time, but if it makes sense to you...

Comment: Protip: use `DATEPART( iso_week, ... )` to get the week-number for `GROUP BY` instead of resorting to textual formatting.

Comment: @DaleK When I used CAST on the GROUP BY the error code was: `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column 'incident.createdon' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` I am trying to format it as much as possible up-stream before I bring it into a BI application.

Comment: @hobosapien Do you understand _why_ you get that error message?

Comment: @Dai Can't say that I do because that column is in the GROUP BY clause which makes it confusing.

Comment: You need the column to be exactly the same i.e. including any functions applied, do if you cast to date in the group by, you have to cast to date in the select.

Comment: You always need to add your exact error message to your question.

Comment: @DaleK Wrapping both in the CAST function is what I needed, and worked. Thank you for that tidbit of info. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to wrap `CAST()` around the `DATEADD` call in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statement, which a fellow SOer advised.

```
SELECT
  owneridname,
  CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date) [week],
  COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [Yes],
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [No] 
FROM incident
WHERE createdon >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) 
GROUP BY
  owneridname,
  CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date)
ORDER BY
  Week DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- This query does not attempt to format date/time as text: doing-so in SQL is an anti-pattern.

  - The formatting of dates, numbers, etc, is a presentation-layer concern.
- Instead, this query preserves the numeric values needed to group by week: the year-number and the week-number: you can reconstitute the first-date-of-weeek in a later CTE step.

  - Using text values for `GROUP BY` will always because it means there'll be string allocations, copies, *and more* going-on inside the DB engine - not to mention *being just plain wrong* for `date` values: using `MM/dd/yyyy` is particularly egregious because you cannot meaningfully lexicographically sort `MM/dd/yyyy` dates anyway.
- Additionally, this query puts the `GROUP BY` aggregation step into a separate named CTE (`aggregatedByOwnerId`), which also means you can inspect `pastFortnightIncidents` independently - and re-use those CTE steps separately.

  - But my main reason for putting the `GROUP BY` separately is to help with the common misconception in SQL that the `SELECT` clause is somehow evaluated *before* `GROUP BY` (fun-fact: it isn't).

    - A common tarpit in SQL is *trying to do too much* in the `SELECT` clause, especially with `GROUP BY`.

Anyway...

```sql
SET DATEFIRST 7 -- I'm assuming you're using Sunday as first-day-of-week.

DECLARE @minCreated datetime2(7) = DATEADD( day, -15, SYSUTCDATETIME() );

WITH
pastFortnightIncidents AS (

    SELECT
        i.owneridname                    AS OwnerIdName,
        i.createdon                      AS Created,
        i.svb_contactname                AS Contact
        DATEPART( year   , i.createdon ) AS CreatedYear,
        DATEPART( week   , i.createdon ) AS CreatedWeek,
        DATEPART( isoweek, i.createdon ) AS CreatedIsoWeek

    FROM
        incident AS i

    WHERE
        i.createdon >= @minCreated
),
aggregatedByOwnerId AS (
    
    SELECT
        i.OwnerIdName,
        i.CreatedYear,
        i.CreatedWeek,
        COUNT(*)                 AS Count_All,
        COUNT( svb_contactname ) AS Count_with_ContactName,
        
    FROM
        pastFortnightIncidents AS i

    GROUP BY
        i.OwnerIdName,
        i.CreatedYear,
        i.CreatedWeek
)
SELECT
    g.OwnerIdName,
    DATEADD(
        week,
        g.CreatedWeek,
        DATEFROMPARTS( g.CreatedYear, /*M:*/ 1, /*d:*/ 1, /*h:*/ 0, /*m:*/ 0, /*s:*/ 0, /*ms:*/ 0 )
    ) AS CreatedWeekStarting,
    g.Count_with_ContactName AS "Yes",
    ( g.Count_All - g.Count_with_ContactName ) AS "No"

FROM
    aggregatedByOwnerId AS g

ORDER BY
    CreatedWeekStarting,
    OwnerIdName
```

Answer (score -1):

Format function may help you,

```
FORMAT([datecolumn],'dd/MM/YYYY')
```

Updated query,

```
SELECT
  owneridname,
  FORMAT(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0),'dd/MM/yyyy') AS [week],
  COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [Yes], 
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [No]
FROM incident
WHERE createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
  owneridname,
  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0)
ORDER BY
  Week DESC;
```

Comment: That won't work, the group by clause needs to match the select column. And format is very expensive, so not a good idea.